# Logging with Grails , choosing log file at runtime

Tags: grails, log4j

I'm working on a Grails 2.3.6 application

Assuming I have multiple users, I want to have for each one a different log file, is it possible to dynamically choose which log file to use at runtime?

Comment: From your tags I assume you use log4j, you question is how to have one log file per user? Did you find anything interesting in the documentation that makes you believe that it is or is not possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Commons logging api manually. The [documentation](http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/2.3.6/guide/conf.html#logging) says you can use something like:

```
class MyClass {
    private static final log = LogFactory.getLog(this)
}
```

The [commons API documentation](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-logging/apidocs/org/apache/commons/logging/LogFactory.html#getLog(java.lang.String)) says you can create a log by `String`, too, so you could create logs with `LogFactory.getLog(userName)` and store them somewhere, perhaps in a `Map`, then retrieve the right one when you need to log, e.g. `loggers[userName].info "Client did X"`